# Is it possible to download jar files or pom files from maven repository using python?

Tags: python, maven, repository

I am trying to write a puthon code that will download the pom file linked to a java package hosted on maven repository.

I am able to perform a search using

```
    url = "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q="
    src = "g:javax.servlet a:javax.servlet-api v:4.0.1"

    response = requests.get(url + src)
    result = response.json()["response"]
    match = result["docs"][0]
    print(match)
```

but a json is returned and do files are found inside.

Even if I manage to get to this page:

Any idea?

Comment: Why using Python? Not using Maven itself? The URL to download artifacts is created via  `URL+groupId+version+artifactId+`

Comment: Because it is mandatory to use python in my project. So the url should be ’https://mvnrepository.com/javax.servlet/4.0.1/javax.servlet-api’, right? But in this case the output contained in response is a capture challange failure.
Shouldnt the url be: ’https://mvnrepository.com/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1’ ? but that is the web page url, not download.

Comment: mvnrepository.com is not a consumable maven repository.... Better use this: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ also the correct groupId/artfiactid would help here like: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used:

```
    import requests

class Downlaoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"   # base url

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def download(self, g, a, v, extension="pom"):
        '''
        This method will manage the different parts of the downloading process
        :param g: groupID
        :param a: artefactID
        :param v: artefact version
        :param ext: set pom if you want to create a link for the pom file,
                    set jar if you want to create a link for the jar file
        :return:
        '''

        self.g = g
        self.a = a
        self.v = v

        url = self.gav_to_url(g, a, v, extension)   #create the url from the GAV format
        #print("jar url = ", url)
        if self.is_downloadable(url):
            return self.perform_download(url)       #return the downloaded file
        else:
            print(f"The url = {url} is not a downloadable URL")
            exit(1)
        return 0

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def gav_to_url(self, g, a, v, ext):
        '''
        This method creates the JAR or POM file link from G:A:V coordinates
        :param g: groupID
        :param a: artefactID
        :param v: artefact version
        :param ext: set pom if you want to create a link for the pom file,
                    set jar if you want to create a link for the jar file
        :return: url pointing to the desired file: jar or pom
        '''

        gid = g.replace(".", "/")
        return self.base + gid + "/" + a + "/" + v + "/" + a + "-" + v + "." + ext

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def perform_download(self, url):
        '''
        Do the downlaod of the file
        :param url: url of the file to be downloaded
        :return:  downloaded file
        '''

        filename = url.split("/")[-1]
        #print("Filename = ", filename)
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
            open(filename, "wb").write(response.content)    # overwritting file in case it exists
        except BaseException as be:
            print(f"Something went wrong while downloading: {url} and the following exception was raised: {be}. Exiting!"
                  f"This operation is mandatory, exiting!")
            exit(1)
        return filename

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def is_downloadable(self, url):
        """
        Does the url contain a downloadable resource ? Checking it examining only the header
        I am aiming for a POM or JAR file, other files will be ignored
        :param url: url of the file to be checked
        :return: True if a target file is actually a POM or JAR file, False otherwise
        """

        h = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
        header = h.headers
        content_type = header.get('content-type')
        if "text/xml" in content_type.lower() or "application/java-archive" in content_type.lower():
            return True
        else:
            print(f"this url doesn't point nor to a POM file neighter to a JAR file but to a {content_type.lower()}")
            return False
```

You call it like this:

```
# POM / JAR downloader
    jd = Downlaoder()
    pom_file_name = jd.download(g, a, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q="
search_query = "g:javax.servlet a:javax.servlet-api v:4.0.1"
response = requests.get(url + search_query)
result = response.json()["response"]["docs"][0]
group_id = result["g"]
artifact_id = result["a"]
version = result["v"]

pom_url = f"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/{group_id.replace('.', 
'/')}/{artifact_id}/{version}/{artifact_id}-{version}.pom"

response = requests.get(pom_url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(f"{artifact_id}-{version}.pom", "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print(f".pom file downloaded successfully: {artifact_id}-{version}.pom")
else:
    print(f"Failed to download .pom file: {response.status_code}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).